# How can I show a new <form:select> which values depends on the choice made in a first <form:select> using Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I have the following problem.

I know that in a JSP page I can use the Spring tag library to create a **select** input field that is automatically binded by a field of a specific bean by Spring framework, something like this:

```
<label>Regioni:</label>
<form:select path="regioneSelezionata">
    <form:options items="${listaRegioni}" itemLabel="desReg" itemValue="codReg" />
</form:select>
```

So it works fine in my page showing the **desReg** value that is a field of the object inside the **listaRegioni** list. When the user select a specific object Spring put the value of the **codReg** field into the **regioneSelezionata** path.

Ok, this works fine.

My problem is that I want to perform the following flow of operation.

1. The user select a specific object into the previous  tag and **don't submit it**.
2. After the selection of a specific object by the previous  tag (without submit) in the backend it is performed a query that retrieve another list of differnt objects and another  is rendered next to the first  (so detailing the search operation).

For example I have to implement a task like this:

The first  show a list of nations. The user select a single nation and after this choice it is shown another  next to the first one in which the user see the list of the city belonging to the chosen nation.

Spring provide a qay to automatically do something like this or have I to implement it manually (using ajax for example)?

Tnx

Comment: use Ajax to populate the second list based on the choice made on the first one

Comment: @RafikBELDI it seems to me that Struts 2 provide something that automatically do it (but maybe i am saying wrong asserion). Are you sure that Spring can't do it automatically in some way?

Comment: Have the same problem. There must be some connection between different drop down menus...

Comment: can anyone have an example of this code to resolve. i also facing same issue.